# haskell: what are some good ways to switch between ghc (for a different base)?

Tags: haskell, version-control

I am a beginner in Haskell so I'm just wondering what are some good ways to switch between different verisons of ghc so that we can still `cabal install` [when the dependency of some Hackage requires an older version of base](https://github.com/BNFC/bnfc/issues/154), rather than running into Dependency tree exhaustively searched like this:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: bnfc-system-tests-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of bnfc-system-tests-0.1.0.0)
rejecting: base-4.8.0.0/installed-901... (conflict: bnfc-system-tests =>
base>=4.5 && <4.8)
rejecting: base-4.8.0.0, 4.7.0.2, 4.7.0.1, 4.7.0.0, 4.6.0.1, 4.6.0.0, 4.5.1.0,
4.5.0.0, 4.4.1.0, 4.4.0.0, 4.3.1.0, 4.3.0.0, 4.2.0.2, 4.2.0.1, 4.2.0.0,
4.1.0.0, 4.0.0.0, 3.0.3.2, 3.0.3.1 (global constraint requires installed
instance)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

I'm using a mac and I installed my haskell platform (with ghc-7.10.1.1) with brew (`brew install ghc & cabal-install`). So I went to grab an older version of haskell platform [here](https://ghcformacosx.github.io/), added an alias for the older version of ghc in my `.zshenv`

```
ghc-78 --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.4
```

and made a new config file in `~/.cabal` with

```
-- compiler: ghc-78
```

But after that when I ran

```
cabal --config-file="./config78" install --only-dependencies --enable-tests
```

in the sandbox directory, I still got into the dependency problem indicating that I was still using ghc 7.10. (So after that I changed the line back to compiler: ghc and added ghc-location:

```
-- ghc-location: the/new/directory/ghc
```

under program-locations and I was still getting the same thing.)

What did I do wrong and what are some good ways to switch between different versions of ghc? (for example in Node.js I can use n, a version control manager)

---

--Update:

Even after I have uncommented the line

```
compiler: ghc-78
```

`cabal --config-file="./config78" install --only-dependencies --enable-tests` would still give me the dependency error (even if I used `--sandbox-config-file` instead ).  `cabal sandbox hc-pkg list base` would show base-4.8.0.0, even if I init sandbox with the config file:

```
cabal --config-file="./config78" sandbox init
```

However,

```
cabal install -w ghc-7.8.4
```

works as long as ghc-7.8.4 is in path, as [suggested by Daniel in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338883/haskell-what-are-some-good-ways-to-switch-between-ghc-for-a-different-base#comment52555830_32338883).

Comment: GHC itself already provides versioned binaries; `ghc-7.8.4` and `ghc-7.10.1` (or similar) should already be in your path. Also, you can specify a version on the `cabal` command line pretty easily with `-w`, as in `cabal install -w ghc-7.8.4` -- no need to create a special separate config file.

Comment: @DanielWagner great tips! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using `stack` for this:

- Download: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/wiki/Downloads
- In-depth guide: https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/08/new-in-depth-guide-stack
- Reddit post on the in-depth guide: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3j6ria/new_indepth_guide_to_stack/

By selecting a resolver you are also selecting a GHC version, so your code will be built with the same GHC that Stackage used. Use a resolver like `lts-2.17` for GHC 7.8.4 or `lts-3.3` for GHC 7.10.2, etc.

Also, I suggest using:

```
system-ghc: false
```

in your `stack.yaml` file so that `stack` always uses its own tool-chain.

Comment: Cool. Saw that on [HN](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9687274) the other day; but didn't have the time to check it out. Just read it up. Great tool.

Answer (score 4):

Lines that start with `--` are treated as comments by Cabal's config file parser. So you should change

`-- compiler: ghc-78`

to

`compiler: ghc-78`

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I missed the comment on the 6th line; & it sure took me long enough to realize it was yaml! But even after uncommenting the line, it still  shows that I am using `base-4.8.0.0`.

Comment: Can it be that ghc.7.8 also use base 4.8? How can I check that? Thanks!

Comment: @ArchWilhes You can check the version of `base` with `ghc-pkg`. For example, `ghc-pkg-7.8.4 list base` will tell you which versions of `base` are installed in GHC 7.8.4's package database. If you are in a cabal sandbox and want to know about packages installed in the sandbox, you should use `cabal sandbox hc-pkg` instead of `ghc-pkg` (which will choose the version of `ghc-pkg` that you asked for during your `configure` step, and will point it at the sandbox's package database).

Comment: @DanielWagner Thank you so much! That is really helpful.

Comment: @DanielWagner I tried `cabal --config-file="./config78" sandbox init` but `cabal sandbox hc-pkg` always shows `base-4.8` (I just updated my question): looks like setting `compiler: ghc-78` does nothing.

Comment: @ArchWilhes I suspect a shell alias is not going to cut it. There's too many ways for that to go wrong: cabal could use a different shell, cabal could use a non-interactive shell (which typically loads fewer configuration files and could mean your alias isn't defined), or cabal could even be doing its own path lookup internally, in a shell-independent way.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks for the explanation! I will look up it on how to work with cabal configure file when I've got the time. For now I will stick to `-w ghc.version` for that and eventually I plan to switch from cabal to stack.

Answer (score 4):

For completion, let me add another option here: [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/). You can easily install and maintain different version of `ghc` simultaneously using Nix.
To switch to a different `ghc` version all you have to do is:

```
nix-shell -p haskell.compiler.ghc7102
```

Or if you want a 7.8.4 version, then:

```
nix-shell -p haskell.compiler.ghc784
```

In case `ghc 7.10.2` or the other version isn't installed, Nix will automatically download and install them for you. ( The next time you give this command, it will obviously reuse the installed component.) Once you are inside the nix-shell environment you can navigate to your package directory, and build your haskell package there. Note that you can build your haskell package either using the usual `cabal` command there or `nix-build`.

More information about Nix and Haskell can be obtained [in this manual](https://hydra.nixos.org/job/nixpkgs/trunk/manual/latest/download-by-type/doc/manual#users-guide-to-the-haskell-infrastructure).